# When I tried to connect aws ec2 machine getting connection closed

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

```
$ ssh -v -i "infra.pem" ubuntu@13.233.128.254 -p 22
OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 13.233.128.254 [13.233.128.254] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
load pubkey "infra.pem": invalid format
debug1: identity file infra.pem type -1
debug1: identity file infra.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to 13.233.128.254:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:0NftNS5VQtaGmmOsUOZzxdYwnQ/hSwF2e7SDizNp6Ew
The authenticity of host '13.233.128.254 (13.233.128.254)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:0NftNS5VQtaGmmOsUOZzxdYwnQ/hSwF2e7SDizNp6Ew.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '13.233.128.254' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: infra.pem  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: infra.pem
Connection closed by 13.233.128.254 port 22
```

''
While trying to connect the aws ec2 getting the above issue & I have checked SG as well which contains allowed all traffic with 0.0.0.0/0".Plase help me to fix this issue.Thanks.
''

Comment: Can you add `-v` to the ssh command to get more info.

Comment: OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 13.233.128.254 [13.233.128.254] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.

Comment: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to 13.233.128.254:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent

Comment: You can updated your question with properly format output.

Comment: I have updated once again

Comment: The error msg says `load pubkey "infra.pem": invalid format`. Where and how did you generated this file? Did you edit it?

Comment: The error msg says load pubkey "infra.pem": invalid format
This error is ignorable as i faced previously as well  and after that I could able to connect. The key is generated when I created  VM on aws

Comment: see while i'm connecting another VM getting same error but I could able to connect
ssh -i aws-cicd.pem ec2-user@15.206.88.66
load pubkey "aws-cicd.pem": invalid format
Last login: Wed Dec  9 15:52:02 2020 from 157.47.67.5

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux 2 AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/
29 package(s) needed for security, out of 49 available
Run "sudo yum update" to apply all updates.